# backup/restore data in mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, backup-strategies

How to backup/restore data in mysql database very quickly?

Comment: I need this to switch between test data and live, have to do this several times so need fast solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`mysqldump` command line is the quickest to backup ,

(use mysql command line to restore , `mysql -u #username# -p #database# < #dump_file#`)

look on this [examples](http://www.databasef1.com/tutorial/mysql-backup-tutorial.html?page=2)

Comment: great, will try in batch file, hopefully using same batch file, it 'll have no issue on windows and linux.

Answer (score 1):

Following will backup and restore db at same time.

> mysqldump -h #host  -u #username -p #password  --routines #source_dbname | mysql -h #host  -u  #user -p #password #destination_dbname